# Javascript: undefined is not a function

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

This is my code for my controller:

```
Ext.define(controller.details.StudentControlller', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    requires: [
    ],
    config: {
},
Init: function(){
"use strict";
        var me = this;
        this.app = this.getApplication();
    this.createStudentTables();
}
createStudentTables: function () {
var finalStudent=[],
view=this.getStudentsTableView();

arrReqTplTest = ['<div class="StuReq"><table><tr><th class=" StuReq ">' +
                'NAME  ' +
                '<img src="resources/images/arrow-bottom-1-512.png" width="10px" height="10px" onclick="this.sortStore();"/>' +
                '</th><th class=" StuReq ">CATEGORY ' +
                ' <img src="resources/images/arrow-bottom-1-512.png" width="10px" height="10px" onclick="sortStore();"/>' +
                '</th><th class=" StuReq ">STUDENT GROUP  ' +
                '<img src="resources/images/arrow-bottom-1-512.png" width="10px" height="10px" onclick="sortStore();"/>' +                
</th></tr></table></div>'];
finalStudent.push({
title: “Student Table”,
                collapsed: true,
                layout: 'fit',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'component',
                        itemId: 'StudentTablViewID-' + i,
                        html: arrReqTplTest

                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'dataview',
                        itemId: 'StudentTable-' + i,
                        height: 200,
                        store: ‘studentDetailStore’,
                        //itemHeight: 70,
                        scrollable: false,           
                        itemSelector: 'div.wrap-requirements-' + i
                    }
                ]
            });
        }

        view.add(finalStudent);
})
}
sortStore: function(){
        alert("Now it is finally undefined");
    }
});
```

In the code above you can see that I have written an onclick for images that I have attached next to column headers. When I click on that image it is supposed to call the function called as sortStore but it just keeps throwing the error called "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Please forgive me if I have done some syntax errors, its because I have shortened the code to make it readable. But rest assured everything except sortStore() calling works fine from onclick event works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/536

I created this as a panel and attached a event listener to the img element like this.

```
Ext.define('test.view.SignupPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'mypanel',
    config: {
      itemId: 'testItem',
      layout: 'fit',
      html:'<img  src="http://www.sencha.com/img/v2/logo.png"/>',
      listeners:{
        initialize:function(obj){ 
               var me= this;
               obj.element.down('img').on('tap', me.imageTap, this, me);
            }
      }
    },
    imageTap:function(obj){
        Ext.Msg.alert('Hi', this.xtype);
    }
```

});

Comment: Hey I tried your code but I am not getting the alert. Could you please try it out on my Component. It is in the question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are binding a listener with a string. This listener will only fire if you have a function `sortStore` on the global level (window). This listener will never execute in the current scope like you expected it too.

The recommended way is to make an `Ext.Img` and bind a click listener to it. Or use the `xtype: 'image'`.

```
Ext.create('Ext.Img', {
    src: 'resources/images/arrow-bottom-1-512.png',
    listener: {
        click: function(){ ... }
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean like I have to do Ext.create....... on global level and then how would I add it in the html that I have in the code

Comment: And will I lose the scope when I am calling the function if it is declared on Global level